# What's wrong with my ruby gems setup?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to run a ruby file which imports a gem. The ya2yaml gem is installed, yet somehow it is not found:

```
$ cat delme.rb  
require 'rubygems'  
require 'ya2yaml'  

$ ruby delme.rb  
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- ya2yaml (LoadError)  
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'  
        from delme.rb:2
```

I installed the gem using:

```
sudo gem install ya2yaml
```

and I know that the gem is actually installed:

```
$ gem list --local | grep ya2yaml
ya2yaml (0.26)
```

Also, the following works from a rails program I just downloaded:

```
sudo rake gems
```

However the following fails:

```
rake gems
```

Which leads me to think that there may be a permissions problem somewhere.

Why can't the gem be found? What can I do to diagnose this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do other gems work as normal?

Comment: Some do, some don't. The following lists many gems which are having trouble:

for gem in `gem list --local | sed -e "s/ .*//"`; do ruby -rrubygems -e "require '$gem'"; done | grep 'no such file to load'

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you any further. However, to help other people identify your problem, you may want to indicate your ruby version, your operating system, and how you installed ruby.

Comment: Are the gems that *do* work and the gems that *don't* installed in different locations? What are the `gemhome` and `gempath` in your `~/.gemrc` file?

Comment: **Update:** I think I've figured it out and I think it has to do with a bad mix of the ruby which comes with Mac OS and the ruby which I had installed via MacPorts. I looked at my list of gems using <pre>gem list -d</pre> and saw that my gems had been installed to multiple directories which made me think I should try to consolidate them. So I removed all gems from my system, installed rvm, and reinstalled my gems and all seems to work now. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

The thing I would do in a situation like this:

1. Search for the gem's location on your system. Use this command:

   *find / -name ya2yaml*
2. Check that the found directory is added to your PATH system variable by doing this:

   *echo $PATH*
3. If the path where ya2yaml gem is located is not listed in the PATH variable's value, add it:

   *PATH=$PATH:/gem/location/directory*

   *export PATH*

I hope you'll find these steps helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've certainly seen this error before.  Unfortunately I don't know what causes it.  I do know that if you see it on Linux and you've installed gem via your package manager (synaptic / yum / etc) then you can generally fix it by installing gem by hand from their website.  The instructions there are pretty straight-forward.

(Your command line looks unix-y, so it seems to me that you may be on Linux.  If you're on a Mac, it's certainly worth trying anyway.)

UPDATE: Linux, then.  Ta.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `require 'rubygems'` inside delme.rb, try starting ruby with -rubygems:

```
$ ruby -rubygems delme.rb
```